# cookie.set with domain option param doesn't work

Tags: javascript, cookies

```
const cookies = require('browser-cookies')

export function storeSessionId(sessionId) {
  return (
    isWindow() &&
    cookies.set(SESSION_ID, sessionId, {
      domain: getHost()
    })
  )
}
```

When using it without :

```
{
  domain: getHost()
}
```

domain, it works properly, maybe do smth wrong?

Comment: What is `getHost()`?

Comment: return domain , 'localhost:5000', or will be return my domain string @Barmar

Comment: The domain shouldn't have a port number in it.